# re updating of "Key" value is not reflecting with "ForEach"

Tags: c#

I have a below class where I am setting "Key" value,

```
public class DataCls
{
    private string _key;

    public string Message { get; set; }
    public string Priority { get; set; }
    public string Key
    {
        get
        {
            return _key = $"{Message}:{Priority}";
        }
        set
        {
            _key = value;
        }
    }
}
```

Now, the "Key" value is coming automatically while I am adding some "Message" and "Priority",

```
 List<DataCls> lstData = new List<DataCls>
       {
           new DataCls {Message="M1", Priority="P1" },
       };
```

Now. I would like update the "Key" value again with "ABC".

I tried with below "ForEach", but updated "Key" value's ("ABC") is not reflecting to the list "lstData", what I am missing?

```
lstData.ForEach(p => p.Key = "ABC");
```

Comment: If you change `Key` to simply  `return _key ?? $"{Message ?? "NA"}:{Priority ?? "NA"}";`, how does that go?  Your getter is assigning the constructed string to `_key` and then returning it.

Comment: @Brendan Green, amazingly it's works as expected, but what this ?? mean here?

Comment: That's Null comparison operator, which would select other value if the _Key is null

Comment: @user2994834 see my answer.

Comment: but my Key is not null, it's has some value while updating with "ABC"

Comment: Yes then it show up that value, "ABC" or else string format in later part of ?? operator

Comment: Ok, got it...Thanks!!!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The issue is with your getter for `Key`.

Let's assume that you want to return either the `Key` value that was assigned by some other code, or the combination of `{Message}:{Priority}` otherwise.

Your current code:

```
public string Key
{
    get
    {
        return _key = $"{Message}:{Priority}";
    }
}
```

When you access `Key`, the string of `$"{Message}:{Priority}"` is assigned to `_key`, and then returned.

Therefore, no matter what value you set `Key` to, `$"{Message}:{Priority}"` is always returned.

If you change the get to do this instead:

```
public string Key
{
    get
    {
        return _key ?? $"{Message}:{Priority}";
    }
}
```

With this change, we use the null-coalescing operator, which will returns the left-hand operand if the operand is not null (e.g. `_key`); otherwise it returns the right hand operand (e.g. the string `$"{Message}:{Priority}"`).

You will either return the value that was assigned to `Key`, **or** the string `$"{Message}:{Priority}"` if `_key` is `null` (i.e you haven't assigned anything to it)

Comment: You could guess, what OP needs, I am completely unsure :) +1